# sqlaclhemy - mapping a column to separate table

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have model with a list in it. The list contains id values. These ids need to be stored in separate table and no model is defined for this table in the xsd.

The class models are generated using [generateDS tool](https://www.davekuhlman.org/generateDS.html) from the xsd file automatically.
Basically the id table is like a lookup (association) table which maintains associations between two entities.
How do I handle this scenario?

```
ClassA:
   id String,
   name String,
   listIds String

TableA = ('TableA', meta,
   id String(255),
   name String(255)

TableB = (TableB', meta,
   tableA_id String(255),
   listIds String(255)
```

Comment: Will you please provide the data which you want to store with some explanation of that data?

Comment: Please give the answer and select it to make this question close